# Laravel: User-defined method valiate in Request?

Tags: validation, laravel, callback, user-defined

I use Laravel and have validate code in Request:

```
class InformationsRequest extends Request
{
    // validate rule
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|max:2000',
            'description' => 'required|max:5000'
        ];
    }

    // custom message
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'aaa',
            'description.required' => 'bbb',
        ];
    }
}
```

Today, please help me 2 points:

1. How I make user-defined validate. (checkXXX method)

Method checkXXX maybe has 1 param, 2 param .....

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|max:2000|checkXXX',
        'description' => 'required|max:5000'
    ];
}
```

2. Custom message for checkXXX method

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validator rules in a service provider. [There's more information on this in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

```
Validator::extend('checkXXX', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return $attribute === true;
});
```

Simply return false from the callback if the attribute fails validation.

Then, provide the custom message in either your `lang` files, or return one from the `messages()` method.

```
return [
    'title.checkXXX' => 'The :field failed the checkXXX rule.'
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.